# How to describe the structure of the database to link a table with 2 tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

have the table:

```
class File 
{
  int Id { get; set; } 
  // ...
}
```

and 2 tables that needs to link with File table:

```
class Table1 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  // ...
  int FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Table2
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  // ...
  int FileId { get; set; }
  File File { get; set; }
}
```

but, i have error:

```
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Tables2_dbo.Files_FileId". The conflict occurred in database "dbContext-", table "dbo.Files", column 'Id'
```

How resolve problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually happens when you try to add required FK to a table that already has some records in it. Simplest way to fix this would be to make this relationship optional by specifying ID as null able int:

```
int? FileId { get; set; }
```

If you need to make it required, then you need to fill the data first and then modify it from nullable int to int.